# photoalbum in libreoffice v5

Tags: images, libreoffice, pictures, libreoffice-impress

How do you insert many pictures, say one hundred (100) pictures, into a LibreOffice Impress presentation, one picture per slide...all at once, without having to insert each of 100 images one by one each on its own new page (slide).

[This link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/create-a-photo-slide-show-presentation-in-libreoffice-41/) nicely explains how to `Insert -> Picture -> Photo Album`.

Except, that was v4.1. In the (nearly) current v5.1.4.2, there IS NO `Insert -> Picture` menu any more. There's an `Insert -> Media`, which contains sub menu's of `Image` and `Scan` but `Image` only allows a single image file to be selected.

`View -> Toolbars -> Customize -> Add` doesn't have a `Photo Album` in `Insert` either.

What happened to it?

(Note: there was a [PhotoAlbum Extension](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/photoalbum) but it was replaced by an integrated feature, in v4.1, as far as I can tell, and that extension hasn't been updated since 2012; it's now 2016.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found it. I could not find it in the default menus. But `View -> Toolbars -> Customize -> Menus tab -> Add ->` has it in category `Options`. If you're reading this, that was probably not an obvious place to find it for you, either.